# Access Denied Problem With Only One Browser

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, permissions

I'm currently having a problem with permission rights for a SharePoint site. I have a given page on a SharePoint site and I'm trying to email a link to this page using a hyperlink (through email) to a given group of people. My problem arises when people go to click on the link, it default opens up a Microsoft Edge's browser and they will be denied access to the page. I'm an owner on the site and I'm still denied access to the SharePoint site page when the link loaded through Microsoft Edge (for clarification Microsoft edge is the default browser on the computer). Yet when I open the same link on Google Chrome, I'm able to access the SharePoint site page. Can anyone help me find a way to stop having people's access to a SharePoint site when using Microsoft Edge (without having the user change his default browser to Chrome). 
Thanks in advance.